# Android Tango Explorer Crashing

Tags: google-project-tango

Everytime i am starting Explorer application on Tango device, its crashing will following error, My Tango Core version is 1.43

Process: com.projecttango.tangoexplorer, PID: 4408

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no non-static method "Lcom/google/atap/tangoexplorer/fragments/AreaLearningFragment$1;.onPointCloudAvailable(Lcom/google/atap/tangoservice/TangoPointCloudData;)V"

at com.google.atap.tango.TangoJNINative.ConnectListener(Native Method)

at com.google.atap.tangoservice.Tango.connectListener(Tango.java:451)

at com.google.atap.tangoexplorer.fragments.AreaLearningFragment.onTangoReady(AreaLearningFragment.java:623)

at com.google.atap.tangoexplorer.fragments.TangoExplorerFragment$2.run(TangoExplorerFragment.java:183)

at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:811)

Force finishing activity com.projecttango.tangoexplorer/com.google.atap.tangoexplorer.MainActivity

enqueue first Preview frame or first video frame

calibration-provider.cc:47 Instantiated calibration provider with sources:

CAD: /system/vendor/google/config/calibration_cad_DVT3.xml

Factory: /sdcard/config/calibration.xml

Online: /sdcard/config/online-calibration.xml

calibration-provider.cc:280 Online calibration file provided, but does not exist: /sdcard/config/online-calibration.xml. Reverting to factory calibration.

calibration-provider.cc:315 Trying to load calibration file from helpers.h:166 Loading CAD calibration file from '/system/vendor/google/config/calibration_cad_DVT3.xml'. Source: ro.config.calibration_cad

Focus gain on non-focused client com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@648c0528 (uid=10072 pid=4408)
helpers.h:218 Successfully parsed CAD calibration xml from file [/system/vendor/google/config/calibration_cad_DVT3.xml].

camera-intrinsic-calibration.cc:339 Could not find calibration for camera 4

calibration-provider.cc:151 Failed to load intrinsic calibration for camera 4 from file /sdcard/config/calibration.xml

helpers.h:166 Loading CAD calibration file from '/system/vendor/google/config/calibration_cad_DVT3.xml'. Source: ro.config.calibration_cad

Answer (score 0):

According to the latest [release notes](https://developers.google.com/tango/release-notes), there is an issue with Java apps and Tango Core. You can work around this by downgrading to the previous version of Tango Core.